# zoom and swipe issues

Tags: android, zooming, viewflipper, swipe

I am trying to implement an android application in which I wish to implement both pinch and zoom, swipe operations. For this, I have used view flipper in the layout. The problem I am facing is the following:

1. When I try to implement zoom, I am not able to swipe. The screen goes blank
2. When I try to implement swipe, I am not able to zoom.

I have searched a lot on getting it worked with both but in vain.

Can someone suggest something?

Comment: I have same issue.. did you got any solutions then please post here...thanks